# Помогите с маленьким воросом на паскале

Tags: pascal

```
uses crt;

var
  i, n, x, y, g: integer;


procedure f;
begin
  Delay(100);
  if i > 9 then i := 0;
  TextColor(i+1);
  gotoxy(X * 2, y);
  write(i);
  inc(i);
end;


begin
  read(n);
  clrscr; 
  y := 1;
    for x := 1 to n do f; 
    inc(y);
    for x := x downto 1 do f;
    inc(y);
  readln;
  readln;
end.
```

Объясните как вывести до n-нного Y эти строки?

Answer (score 0):

Вложенные циклы

```
y := 0;
for z := 1 to n/2 do
begin
  for x := 1 to n do f; 
  inc(y);
  for x := x downto 1 do f;
  inc(y);
end;
```

Или так

```
y := 0;
while y <= n do
begin
  for x := 1 to n do f; 
  inc(y);
  for x := x downto 1 do f;
  inc(y);
end;
```

Comment: @roabor а почему убрали y+1 ? Без них же все в одной строке будет

Comment: Потому что `y` меняется оператором цикла. Если нужно первое и второе выводить в разных строках, то между ними можно вставить `inc(y)`. Я особо не вникал в то, что вы там делаете. Если ответ помог, то прошу принять и/или проголовать "за".

Comment: Там просто будет ошибка: Нельзя изменять значение переменной цикла внутри этого цикла, если внутри этого цикла изменять y

Comment: так тоже не работает, там выводятся до y больше чем n

Comment: Границы `y := 0` и `to n/2` или `<= n` вы уже сами как-то подстройте, я же не знаю точно ваших условий.

Comment: @rotobar я не понял про что вы я подставил ваши коды и они оба работают не корректно

Comment: @rotobar `uses crt;

var
  i, n, x, y: integer;

procedure f;
begin
  Delay(100);
  if i > 9 then i := 0;
  TextColor(i+1);
  gotoxy(x , y);
  write(i);
  inc(i);
end;


begin
  read(n);
  clrscr; 
  y:=1;
      repeat 
      
      for x:= 1 to n do f;
      inc(y);
      for x:= n downto 1 do f;
      inc(y);
      until y = n ;
     
    

  readln;
  readln;
end.`
 Я попробовал через repeat until и у меня не получилось

Comment: Нужно написать `until y >= n`, а то можно в `n` не попасть. Цикл начинается с `y:=1` и увеличивает `y` на 2 (3, 5, 7). Если `n` будет чётное (например 24), то условие `until y = n` никогда не будет достигнуто.

Comment: а как правильно написать что бы программа заработал и выводила до n-нного **y**

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, изначальная путаница с переменными, и код должен быть +/- таким:

```
uses crt;

procedure f(x: integer; var i: integer);
begin
  Delay(100);
  if i > 9 then i := 0;
  TextColor(i+1);
  gotoxy(x * 2, i);
  write(i);
  inc(i);
end;

var
  n, x, y: integer;

begin
  read(n);
  clrscr; 
  y := 1;
  for x := 1 to n do f(x, y); 
  WriteLn();
  for x := x downto 1 do f(x, y);
  readln;
  readln;
end.
```